# Simplest way to use a variable in the URL in servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

What is the simplest way to use a variable in the URL in servlets.

Eg. `http://somesite.com/MyServlet/[ID]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called *path info*. You can use [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) to grab it.

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); // "/[ID]"
```

This however includes the leading slash. You may want to substring it away as follows:

```
String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo().substring(1); // "[ID]"
```

This assumes that your servlet is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/MyServlet/*`.

Comment: Nice BalusC, i never used this. When should i prefer this pathinfo over query string?